# Angular2: can't resolve global service

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack

I extended `XHRBackend` class and I want to inject my global service, provided with bootstraping. I tried to inject it through constructor

```
export class AppXHRBackend extends XHRBackend {
    constructor(
        browserXHR: BrowserXhr, 
        baseResponseOptions: ResponseOptions, 
        @Inject(AppState) private app: AppState) {...}
    ...
}
```

But I got `undefined`. Then I tried to resolve it manually through the injector:

```
    export class AppXHRBackend extends XHRBackend {
        constructor(browserXHR: BrowserXhr, baseResponseOptions: ResponseOptions) {
            let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([AppState]);
            let app = injector.get(AppState);
        ...
    }
```

I got instance of `AppState`, but that was new instance, I think it is right, it should be so, but I want to get my singleton service.

Here is how I bootsrap application:

```
bootstrap(App, [
      ...
      AppState,
      provide(ExceptionHandler, {useClass: AppExceptionHandler}),
      provide(XHRBackend, {useClass: AppXHRBackend})
  ])
```

And here is my service:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppState {
   ...
}
```

By the way, my service `AppState` nicely injectes in `AppExceptionHandler` class through it's constructor:

```
export class AppExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandler {
  constructor(@Inject(AppState) private app: AppState) {...}
  ...
}
```

And I don't see extremely big difference between these two extendings, so I can't understand why it's not working for `AppXHRBackend`

Generally speaking, I just want my global service to handle 401, 403, 404 status codes globally. Maybe I go wrong way to this purpose?

**UPD**
Solved by providing via `UseFactory` ty @yurzui:

```
{
  provide: XHRBackend,
  useFactory: (browserXHR: BrowserXhr,
    baseResponseOptions: ResponseOptions,
    xsrfStrategy: XSRFStrategy,
    appState: AppState) => new AppXHRBackend(browserXHR, baseResponseOptions, xsrfStrategy, appState)
  ,
  deps: [BrowserXhr, ResponseOptions, XSRFStrategy, AppState]
}
```

Comment: Does `AppState` have a constructor with parameters?

Answer (score 0):

- `@Inject(AppState)` is redundant if the type of the parameter is also `AppState`
- > I got instance of AppState, but that was new instance, 
  >   let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([AppState]);

That's expected. You created a new injector that is entirely unrelated to the injector your Angular application uses, therefore you get different instances.

What you could do (it's not necessary and not advisable for your current problem) is to inject `Injector` and call `injector.get(AppState)` to get the instance.

- It's hard to tell what the actual problem is from the code snippets. There might be some circular dependency.
- From the Plunker you provided (https://plnkr.co/edit/XVk9SaZgAJnJ1DRsUfWm?p=preview) there the `http` bundle is missing and in your code you need to provide `HTTP_PROVIDERS` **before** your providers that override providers contained in `HTTP_PROVIDERS` - order matters here when overriding providers (like `XHRBackend`).

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/u2N1EVQkq3uKiu9Dp1q6?p=preview)

Comment: If I get you right I should do somethink like that:

`export class AppXHRBackend extends XHRBackend {
    constructor(browserXHR: BrowserXhr, baseResponseOptions: ResponseOptions, private injector: Injector) {
        super(browserXHR, baseResponseOptions);
        console.log(injector);
    }
}`

But I get `undefined`

Comment: Yes, if your problem is caused by circular dependencies.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on. Can you create a Plunker that allows to reproduce and debug? (Plunker template https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5)

Comment: Well, I made it, take a look. But I cannot make it work :(   `zone.js:323Error: (SystemJS) TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`

Comment: At this step everything is good on my local env, but in plunker there is not

Comment: Can you please post the link to the Plunker you created?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I thought I edited your plunk, I never used plunker before. https://plnkr.co/edit/XVk9SaZgAJnJ1DRsUfWm?p=preview

Comment: @Danil Makarkin You need to add `@angular/http` property to  `packages` section in your config.js.

Comment: @yurzui
@GünterZöchbauer
Finally, I can reproduce my problem: the instance of AppState, injected in AppXhrBackend class is `undefined`: https://plnkr.co/edit/XVk9SaZgAJnJ1DRsUfWm?p=preview

Comment: @Danil Makarkin Try to provide `AppXhrBackend` class via `useFactory` https://plnkr.co/edit/GNEObDWcqHNW914Ccbe1?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui Perfectly, that's works, thank you very much!